# Open specific Worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

i have a problem to open an Excelfile (from a Sharepoint Server) to a specific Sheet (eg. Sheet3).

I have already tried:

```
http://PathToFile/PathtoFile/Excelfile.xlsx#Sheet3
```

or 
`http://PathToFile/PathtoFile/Excelfile.xlsx#Sheet3!A1`

or `http://PathToFile/PathtoFile/Excelfile.xlsx#'Sheet3'!A1`

or `http://PathToFile/PathtoFile/Excelfile.xlsx#"Sheet3"!A1`

but no one of this Links open the right sheet... I only get the download massage from IE and it opens the last opened Sheet.

Do i make any big misstake?
I am using Office 2016 (at a PC, non Mac).

I hope someone can help me with this Problem and sorry for my bad English ;-)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Excel files will open to the sheet that was active when the workbook was last saved. AFAIK there is no command line or URL parameter to set a specific sheet to be active when the file is opened.

You may want to use a Workbook_Open event in VBA to force the workbook to display a specific sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Is it possible, that this feature is canceled by security issues in Office? Because Aziz Kabyshev gives at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/172039 a nice explanation, that it should work.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: I am not sure, what do you mean with "Client" in the context of Office? But my setup is the following:
SharePoint 2013 on a Microsoft Server 2012, at the client side I use a win 10 64-bit with Office 2016 (64-bit), I also use Internet Explorer to get the Excel File from the SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way too long on this very problem. My use case was simpler: I maintain a fairly complex set of account data in Excel and needed to expose certain reports on it (pivot tables, queries) to salespeople.

Appending `ActiveCell=CellName` didn't work but using the `Item=itemName` URL parameter did. I just made sure that every table had a unique name. I then grabbed the Sharepoint URL from Share | Copy Link and appended the appropriate parameter, e.g., `Item=report_name_of_table`.

Not pretty, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First create a named range for the table or data on the spreadsheet you want to link to.  Now that I think of it I don't think it's necessary.  But do it if all else fails.  :-)

At the end of your file path add this `?web=1?range='YourWorksheetName'`
Where `YourWorksheetName` will be the name of the worksheet or the table range name.

Your final path will look something like this assuming it's an Excel you are linking to in a SharePoint data library...

```
http://xxx/xxxxxx/xx/archmetrics/Data%20Library/3Q%202018%20Reporting.xlsx?web=1?range='TimeInPhase'
```